# What is the status of Gods other than Vishnu in Dwaita?

Tags: vedanta, dvaita

According to Dvaita, there are three categories. Jada, Jeeva and Ishwara.

Now Ishwara is Narayana. What are other Gods or Devathas? Like Lakshmi, Brahma, Saraswathi, Rudra, Devi, Indra, Surya etc etc

Are these Jeevatmas, if so are these Mukthathmas or Bandhatmas?, If these are Bandhatmas where will they go after Mukthi?

Or are these Avathara roopas like Rama, Krishna and Vishnu (One for the Adityas, A form of Narayana) or Amsha Roopas like Parashurama and Kapila etc etc

Please if you can give references it will be helpful.

Comment: According to madvacharya Rama Krishna are not different from moola swaroopa of lord they are not amsa as you mentioned

Comment: @prasanna R oh ok maybe like Parashurama and Kapila. I will edit the question

Comment: Even Dwaitins don't differentiate between Parashuramm Kapila and moola swaroopa

Comment: Yes @Krishna Varna  In dashavatra Balaram is not there because he is avesha of Vishnu is there Kapil's is very much there as moolaroopa but there is later Kapila who ignored God

Comment: @KrishnaVarna wait a second is there no aveshavathara and amshavathara concept in dwaita

Comment: Gods Nail are not different from God himself.. so there is not concept of amsha avatar but avesha is different concept altogether

Comment: Ok so what are the devatas jeevatmas or paramatmas?

Comment: devatas are satvik  jeeva there is no or little rajasic.. quality no tamasic quality until unless they are having asura avesha

Comment: @PrasannaR what? So Lakshmi is a Jeevatma?

Comment: http://madhwabrahmanas.blogspot.com/2009/03/devata-taratamya.html

Comment: @PrasannaR Ok so all the devatas are jeevatmas. But if Vayu is Jeevottama why is Lakshmi, Brahma are higher in taratamya? And are all devathas nithyamukthaas? The blog does not mention this. If all the Devathas are mukthatha jeevis, then why Vayu jeevottama, as he is not the highest in taratamya.

Comment: Lakshmi is always there with Narayana she is jeeva for Narayana alone, otherwise for all the normal jeevatma she is avayktha she is the one keeps the brahmanda in samsara as per command of Narayana.. and also abhimani devatha for all the atoms and sub atoms of the universe here for Vayu jeevotama at what level he is at the devatha level below brahma and lakshmi.

Comment: Vayu is the life breath of all the living entities that  is why he is jeevottama.. Vayu is the one who is the molecular force that binds up the bodies of all the jeevathama in sthula, sukshma and linga level. From brindharankaya upanishad the same is stated by yagnya valkaya if  life breath is out jeeva is dead inthat level vayu is jeevothama you cannot say the same for all the devathas

Comment: I agree that Vayu is the life breath of Jeevis. But is he life breath of Lakshmi, Brahma?? They are put above him in Taratamya for a reason.

Comment: As you go higher up the devatha taratamya, this devathas remain dormant becuase they exist as per command of higher devatha.. so Brahma and Vayu are in the same level.. they have influence till brahmanda as Lakshmi reside outside brahmanda they have no influence.. Life breath of God is vedas themselves.. no need for Vayu

Comment: @PrasannaR ok so confirm this, So Shri Hari is Paramatma. And everyone else is Jeevatma. So all these Gods are muktatmas. Am I right?

Comment: Yes Sir you got it may be get advice from dwaita experts..

Comment: @PrasannaR thank you so much, you could have written an answer. But anyways thank you.There is little digital info on this online. At least I didn't find any. So I asked here. Thank you again

Comment: U R welcome please listen youtube video if by any chance you are kannadiga  plenty of material available in Kannada for tttattva vada i basically listen to Bannanje Govindhacharya  please check this resources to expand your knowledge in tattva vada.. https://www.quora.com/From-where-can-I-get-works-of-Madhvacharya-like-Brahmasutra-Bhashyam-Gita-Bhashyam-etc-in-Sanskrit-or-English

Comment: Yes I am a Kannadiga and Bangalorean. Thank you for the sources

Answer (score 1):

1.When Paramatma is One and only one, every other sentient being is considered a jiva, with a catch- except Lakshmi, the divine mother, who is in a class of her own. The chetanas are classified into dukhasprshta and tadasprshta, only Rama or Lakshmi is in the second category- nityaadukhaa ramaanyetu sprshta dukhaa: samastasha: (Sri Madhva, Tatvasankhyanam). Only Goddess Lakshmi is nityamuktaa. All others starting from Chaturmukha Brahma and Mukhyaprana, the Brahma in the next kalpa, are currently in samsara only.

The current Brahma at the end of his kalpa, takes all those whose sadhana has fructified into aparoksha jnana into Mukthi- Muktha Vaikuntha, leaving those at the higher levels who are capable of doing sadhana for many more kalpas to assume the positions of Brahma, Vayu, Shesha, Rudra etc in the succeeding kalpas.

2.In the Madhva system, all avataras are poorna only and are not different from the Mula rupa of the paramatma. The shruti vakya "neha naanaasti kinchana" means that there is no svagata bheda in the Paramatma- whether in the mula rupa itself, or between the mula and the avatara forms. The former means that his eyes (or for that matter, any other part) are not different from his legs and hands or tongue and viceversa.

Comment: Please give references to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Madhwism has a complete gradation (Taratamya) of divinities.

http://www.sripurandaraashrama.org/dasasahitya/articles/Taratamya.pdf

Here is the top 10:

> 1). shrI viShNu - sarvOththama:
>
> 2). shrI MahA LakshmI dEvi - nithya mukthaLu:
>
> 3).a) shrI BraHma
>   b) shrI MukhyaprANa VAyu
>   c) All RujUs
>
> 4).a) shrI Sarasvathi Devi(Dharmapathni of Lord Brahma)
>   b) shrI BhArathi Devi(Dharmapathni of Lord MukhyaprANa VAyu)
>   c) All RujupathnIs
>
> 5). a) shrI Garuda
>   b) shrI ShESha
>   c) shrI Rudhra
>
> 6). shrI krUShNA's ShaNmahishi's
>   a) shrI JAmbavathi
>   b) shrI Bhadhra
>   c) shrI NIla
>   d) shrI KAlimdhi
>   e) shrI Mithravimdha
>   f) shrI LaxaNa
>
> 7).a) shrI SauparaNi (Dharmapathni of shrI garuda)
>   b) shrI VAruNi (Dharmapathni of shrI shESha)
>   c) shrI PArvathi (Dharmapathni of shrI rudhra)
>
> 8).a) shrI Imdhra (sachIpathi)
>   b) shrI KAma
>
> 9). shrI AhamkArika prANa
>
> 10).a) shrI SvAyambhu Manu
>   b) shrI DhaxaprajApathi
>   c) shrI BRuhaspathyAchArya
>   d) shrI Shachi (Dharmapathni of shrI imdhra)
>   e) shrI Rathi (Dharmapathni of shrI kAma)
>   f) shrI AnirudhDha (Son of shrI kAma)